# How do I work around tracking of transient ViewModels with Castle Windsor in MVVM WPF

Tags: wpf, mvvm, castle-windsor

With Castle Windsor every component is tracked by default, even if it's the lifestyle is configured as transient. How do I deal with this in a WPF MVVM application? I don't want to create (or register using the Typed Factory Facility) a factory for every ViewModel type and release every instance I create, but I accept it if that's the only solution.

I know about the `NoTrackingReleasePolicy`, and I also know that using it means you're probably doing something wrong, but could it perhaps work for MVVM with singleton services and transient ViewModels only?

Is there perhaps a possibility to use child containers for the ViewModels which use the NoTrackingReleasePolicy?

Comment: [This post](http://kozmic.net/2010/08/27/must-i-release-everything-when-using-windsor/) by the primary author of Windsor is worth a read.  In a nutshell, release only what you explicitly resolve.

Comment: I'm very familiar with that post, which is why I'm asking this question.